# qListView custom display & Lync presence indicator issue

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I've got a basic list of users with some roles & features and am using qlist to display them how I want on the main page. The only problem is that I cannot get the Lync presence indicator to work with a Custom Display.

If I just use the default Sharepoint List View or the Quest 'Display Fields' one without custom display, it's fine but I cannot get the presence indicator to work using custom. I'm really hoping that I'm missing something super simple...

The normal Display Field looks like this (tickbox for 'Enable Presence' checked) and the Lync indicator is there:

```
<Fields LookupThresholdControlSetting="Default">
<Field Name="Name" Presence="true" GroupExpanded="false" />
<Field Name="Responsible for..." />
</Fields>
```

The bit of my custom display that's not working so well is here (pulling some other fields too but they're fine). The Lync indicator doesn't appear:

```
<td valign="top" style="font-size:14px; padding:2px;">
<a href="mailto:<%EMail%>"><%Name%></a><br>
<%Job Title%><br>
<%Telephone Number%><br>
<%Responsible for...%>
</a> </td>
```

I have a workaround that displays the indicator (non-custom display) but I don't like it so would like to have my custom one.

Can anyone tell me if adding the equivalent of *Presence="true"* is possible with a Custom Display? The name field is pulling AD details with Lync presence.

*update*
I have come a little further with this and now have a Lync icon appearing with the correct details etc...but it's showing everyone as offline (unless hovered over in which case it's fine..)

```
<td valign="top" style="font-size:14px; padding:2px;">
        <img src="/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif" onload="IMNRC('<%EMail%>')" id="<%ID%>" name="imnmark<%ID%>" ShowofflinePawn = "1" border="0" height="12" valign="middle" /><a href="mailto:<%EMail%>"><%Name%></a><br>
        <%Job Title%><br>
        <%Telephone Number%><br>
        <%Responsible for...%>
        </a>
    </td>
```

FIXED

FIXED - Dell Forums came through with a solution.

```
<td valign="top" style="font-size:14px; padding:2px;">
<span><img src="/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif" onload="IMNRC('<%EMail%>')" id="QAIMID<%ID%>" name="imnmark<%ID%>" ShowofflinePawn = "1" border="0" height="12" valign="middle" /><a href="mailto:<%EMail%>"><%Name%></a></span>       
<br>
<%Job Title%><br>
<%Telephone Number%><br>
<%Responsible for...%>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```